# Azure cloud service deployment issue

Tags: azure, deployment

I uploaded the pkg and confi in azure portal for deploying in staging environment and azure portal shows notification that 'Successfully started to deploy application...successfully started to deploy application to the staging environment for cloud service ...". There after no error or notification, neither the deployment ever visible/happen. What to look for?  I looked into activity logs and there is operation 
Write DeplymentSlot" with status Accepted.

Comment: What's on "Instances" tab?

Comment: @sharptooth, instance tab contain my earlier version of service running for which I  updated some fix and trying to deploy the new pkg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a bug in the new Azure portal. It upload the faulty config file. If in the ACL the ip in quote "x.x.x.x" is replaced with "`x.x.x.x" (note the apostrophe after double quotes) then the new portal upload the file without any error but the deployment shows strange behavior. it notify successful deployment but actually nothing deployed. Also the deployment label got updated with one that actually failed to deploy. The old portal is come as rescue as it is able to catch the bug in first place. Hope Microsoft azure team will look into this.

Comment: Was this reported to Microsoft?